# XAMPP 7.2.10-0 - Application Manager (manager-osx) blank buttons

Tags: macos, xampp, macos-mojave

For the first time, I've just installed XAMPP for OS X 7.2.10 / PHP 7.2.10 on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), that is running macOS Mojave Version 10.14. After installing, it opened Application Manager (aka manager-osx) but it appears that the buttons in the Application Manager app are all blank.

I've seen another post here regarding the blank buttons, which had one answer from a very kind contributor who included a Photoshopped version of the screenshot of the "Manage Servers" tab, with button labels typed in for the "Manage Servers" tab only.

But, the "Welcome" tab and the "Configure Apache Web Server" dialog box both have buttons with no labels as well. Could someone please replicate the Photoshopped version of the screenshots (included below this text) with the button labels typed in? I'm especially wanting to see whether the buttons might help me figure out why the "Manage Servers" tab indicates that the "Apache Web Server" server indicates that it's "Stopped".

[XAMPP Application Manager - Welcome tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw1wV.png)

[XAMPP Application Manager - Configure Apache Web Server dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrGD6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same problem since upgrading to Mojave. I would suggest ditching the manager-osx app and just using the XAMPP command line app.

I no longer open manager-osx.app and just do it all via terminal.

In terminal you can start your webserver with:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start
```

**You may need to change the above path to match your installation.**

You can see the status of your webserver with

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp status
```

You can get a list of commands by running

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp help
```

Answer (score 2):

i found the fix,

1. right click on manager-osx
2. select show original

[image]

3. a lot of folders will coming, double click the manager-osx on here... and wala, the xampp gui will show up

[image]